# LWAPlugin64BitInstaller32 is not installed

Tags: firewall, lync, skype-for-business

I have a Probem with joining a meeting with other Company that is adjusted by **Skype-For-Business**.
They send us a Meeting Link and our Email is added to this meeting ,so  We are invited to this meeting, but when we click on Meeting Link it say's that we have to install "LWAPlugin64BitInstaller32" to make a connection with our Browser.I've installed it but Browser can't understand it. When I open the meeting from Skype For Business Application there is no one in the meeting and we always have to make a Telephone call to  join to the meeting.
here is a link that maybe will help me:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2409256/you-can-t-connect-to-skype-for-business-online--or-certain-features-do
but i don't know how to Allow outgoing connections to a destination.
we use Office 365 2016 in our Company. We can make a metting in our Company without any problem and all of the TCP/UDP needed Ports for Skype are open.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked another company and found out that they use Lync 2013 on their server and skype-for-bussiness-2017 for their clients.
but we always use the last update of office 365. what should we do to make a meeting with skype for bussiness without any probem?